# Помогите найти решение по декораторам

Tags: python, декоратор

Написать функцию, которая просит ввести имя и выводит на экран "Привет и введённое имя".
Далее написать к функции декоратор, который изменяет функцию и переводит имя в заглавные буквы.
У меня при выводе получается Привет Андрей АНДРЕЙ, а должно быть Привет АНДРЕЙ

```
a = input("Введите Ваше имя: ")
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        func()
        print(a.upper())
    return wrapper
@decorator
def imy():
    print("Привет", a, end=' ')
imy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func().upper()

    return wrapper


@decorator
def imy():
    return input("Введите Ваше имя: ")


print("Привет, ", imy())
```

```
Введите Ваше имя: Андрей
Привет,  АНДРЕЙ
```

Comment: Всего то надо было привет не в функцию вставить, ну я окунь))), Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АндрейЦалко это не соответствует изложенному вами заданию **Написать функцию, которая просит ввести имя и выводит на экран "Привет и введённое имя"**